# 1000 digit number is Fibonacci number or not

Tags: math, hash, fibonacci, largenumber

I was doing a problem on Codechef of November COOK-OFF, in which I have to find whether a given 1000 digit number is Fibonacci number or not.

I know the property that if n is fibonacci number then `5n^2 + 4` or `5n^2 - 4` is a perfect square but I found a much simpler approach here.

http://www.codechef.com/viewsolution/2996264

Can anybody please explain me why this is working ???

Here is the link for the question

http://www.codechef.com/COOK40/problems/AMIFIB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That solution *doesn't* work.  It says things are Fibonacci numbers which aren't.  For example:

```
dsm@notebook:~/coding$ ./a.out 
10
768049
YES
958938
YES
1345527
YES
2334421
YES
1000000009
YES
1000000010
YES
1000000011
YES
1000000012
YES
1070066266382758936764980584457396885083683896632151665013235203375314520604694040621889147582489792657804694888177591957484336466672569959512996030461262748092482186144069433051234774442750273781753087579391666192149259186759553966422837148943113074699503439547001985432609723067290192870526447243726117715821825548491120525013201478612965931381792235559657452039506137551467837543229119602129934048260706175397706847068202895486902666185435124521900369480641357447470911707619766945691070098024393439617474103736912503231365532164773697023167755051595173518460579954919410967778373229665796581646513903488154256310184224190259846088000110186255550245493937113651657039447629584714548523425950428582425306083544435428212611008992863795048006894330309773217834864543113205765659868456288616808718693835297350643986297640660000723562917905207051164077614812491885830945940566688339109350944456576357666151619317753792891661581327159616877487983821820492520348473874384736771934512787029218637250627825
YES
```

(where the last number is fib(4782) + 1000000009).  However, I think it should (correctly) return YES for all Fibonacci numbers of <= 1000 digits.

Comment: Thanks @DSM, That is what I wanted to confirm, because taking modulo with 10^9 + 7 will give same remainder for many numbers of 1000 digits, so how can we say that they are all fibonacci number or not fibonacci number. right ??

Comment: @user2098384: that's right.  It can be used to rule out certain numbers -- if you take all the 1000-digit Fibonacci numbers and take their values mod m, and the 1000-digit number you're testing has a value mod m not in that group, then you can rule it out.  But you can't rule numbers in.

Comment: Sir, is there any better way of doing it in c++ or c, because in JAVA people have used Big Integer and did it easily.

Comment: If I had to do this in C++, and we weren't allowed to use external libraries, I think I'd write a small bigint class myself and use that.  I tend to submit solutions in higher-level languages, though, precisely to avoid having to reimplement basic functionality like that.